# Pyspark: Get index of array element based on substring

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have the following dataframe, that contains a column of arrays (`col1`). I need to get the index of the element that contains a certain substring ("58=").

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|                                                      col1 |a_pos|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|[8=FIX.4.4, 55=ITUBD264, 58=AID[43e39b2e-c6e2-4947]        |    0|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

I've tried to use `array_position(col1, "58=")`, but it seems it only works with the exact match and not substrings.

In Python i'm doing exactly this, but in pandas, by using the following code:

```py
df['idx'] = [max(range(len(l)), key=lambda x: '58=' in l[x]) for l in df['col1']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check existence of `58` using the `rlike` function in a higher order function. Determine position using `array_position`. Code below

```py
df = df.withColumn('index',expr("array_position(transform(col1, x-> rlike(x,58)),true)")).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+
|col1                                               |a_pos|index|
+---------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+
|[8=FIX.4.4, 55=ITUBD264, 58=AID[43e39b2e-c6e2-4947]|0    |3    |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+
```